# why can't get value from lua in redis

Tags: go, redis, lua

I use lua to save. the data to redis.
`redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], cjson.encode(ARGV[1]))`

ARGV[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MLLc.png) is the go struct.

[The go code to pass the struct to redis lua](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlq5h.png)

here is my struct looks like

```
type InviteInfo struct {
...
MaxPeers     int32                `json:"maxPeers"`
RouteVersion int32                `json:"routeVersion"`
...
}
```

and use below lua to query the data.

```
local data = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])

    -- Parse JSON
    local inviteInfo = cjson.decode(data)

    -- Compare routeVersion
    if tonumber(inviteInfo['routeVersion']) ~= tonumber(ARGV[1]) then
        return "route version mismatch"
    end
```

the inviteInfo['routeVersion'] is always nil

I expect the inviteInfo['routeVersion'] should be number value instead of nil.

I tried the lua in local redis and works, weird why don't work in staging..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MLLc.png)

**Update, issue fixed**

the previous flow is

1. pass go struct to lua -> cjson.encode -> save
2. get data from redis -> cjson.decode -> invite.routeVersion (this don't work) -> save

changed to

1. go struct -> json.marshal -> pass string to lua -> save
2. get data from redis -> cjson.decode -> invite.routeVersion (this works) -> save

**The difference**.
i queried the saved data in redis.
previously the saved data looks like {\"routeVersion\":1}.
after change, the saved data looks like {"routeVersion"}

Comment: Edit the question to show how the `InviteInfo` value is passed to the Redis server.

Comment: @CeriseLimón hi, i edited the question and uploaded a screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlq5h.png

Answer (score 1):

The good way to to do it, which will certianly work -

when you are saving the data in redis, first initialize struct and fill data fields prior saving,  use `json.Marshal` to get bytes and save that in redis using `SET` command and fetch using `GET` command you will get the data in `bytes` and then use `json.Unmarshal` to retrieve the data.

```
local data = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
// data returned here in bytes
inviteInfo := &InviteInfo {}
err = json.Unmarshal(data, inviteInfo)
    if err != nil {
    // log err 
        return  err
}

// now you can access data fields of inviteInfo if no err
```

Edit 1

```
when saving  - 

type InviteInfo struct {
...
MaxPeers     int32                `json:"maxPeers"`
RouteVersion int32                `json:"routeVersion"`
...
}

inviteInfo := &InviteInfo{
  MaxPeers: 5,
  RouteVersion: 1,
}

inviteInfoBytes, err := json.Marshall(inviteInfo)
if err != nil {
  // log err
}

// method can defer as per library 
func (c *Cache) saveInRedis(key string, inviteInfoBytes []byte) error {
   conn, err := c.getConnFromPool()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    var luaScript = redis.NewScript(1, `
         redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
    `)

    _, err = luaScript.Do(conn, key, string(inviteInfoBytes))

    return err
}

// atomic modification 
func ModifyInviteInfoAtomic(key string, updatedRouteVersion int32) error {
conn, err := c.getConnFromPool()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
 var luaScript = redis.NewScript(1, `
        local inviteInfo = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
         if inviteInfo then:
           local metaData = cjson.decode(inviteInfo)
            if metaData['RouteVersion'] then
               metaData.RouterVersion = ARGV[1]
               local updatedMetaData = cjon.encode(metaData)
               redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], updatedMetaData)
             end
          end
               
    `)
_, err = luaScript.Do(conn, key, updatedRouteVersion)
   return err
}
```

Comment: is it go instead of lua, right?   
yes, this should works.  But my use case need do some logic in lua to make these commands atomic, the actual lua script is more complex than the posted one.

Comment: As not aware of actual usecase, while saving in redis if you are passing the actual struct and not byte, then waht does `cjon.encode` achieve i fail to understand. i guess encoding also just return `jsonString`. so encoding is not needed. now let's say some field if struct you want to modify atomically, then first you have `decode`-> modify -> `encode` -> save.

Comment: cjson.encode do the same thing as json.Marshal.    

decode-> modify -> encode -> save, yes this is what i do, but failed to get the inviteInfo['routeVersion'] after decode

Comment: changed to save string instead of go struct, works thanks

Comment: hi @shawn if my answer helped in fixing the issue, please mark it answered or helpful. thanks.